# How to remove duplicates from the format item in dataframe cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as the **df1** below. And I want to remove the items which are duplicate from the item that contains `-`. For example, the *row 1* and *row 3* will remove `1A` and `1A`, `2B` respectively, just as **df2**. 
How can I  remove the duplicates?

Dataframe:

```py
df1 = DataFrame({'Condition': ['1A', '1A, 1A-1A', '1A, 2B', '1A, 2B, 1A-2B', '3C, 1A-2B']})

df1
    Condition
0   1A
1   1A, 1A-1A
2   1A, 2B
3   1A, 2B, 1A-2B
4   3C, 1A-2B
```

Target output:

```py
df2 = DataFrame({'Condition': ['1A', '1A-1A', '1A, 2B', '1A-2B', '3C, 1A-2B']})

df2
    Condition
0   1A
1   1A-1A
2   1A, 2B
3   1A-2B
4   3C, 1A-2B
```

Comment: What should be the output for row `1A, 1A, 2B-2B` ?

Comment: You can do that using a **lambda** function, but you might want to separate the conditions in different columns, for clarity.

Comment: The output will just still be `1A, 1A, 2B-2B`. The judgment is based on the value of `XX-XX`which contains `-`.

Comment: yes, I would separate the conditions in the follow-up steps. So I want to pre-process the duplicate items first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ca create sets with values with `-` and test if splitted values are not in sets, last join back by `,`:

```
L = []
for x in df1['Condition']:
    a = x.split(', ')
    s = set([z for y in a if '-' in y for z in y.split('-')])
    L.append(', '.join([z for z in a if z not in s]))

df1['new'] = L
print (df1)
       Condition        new
0             1A         1A
1      1A, 1A-1A      1A-1A
2         1A, 2B     1A, 2B
3  1A, 2B, 1A-2B      1A-2B
4      3C, 1A-2B  3C, 1A-2B
```